# How to bring bar and \sim symbol at the same level

Tags: math-mode, accents

I am trying to bring the bar over $\rho$ and \sim over $u_i$ at the same level in the following equation (second term) but unable to do so. Kindly help me on how to do it? Someone told me to go for \strut but I am unable to get this command. I tried but failed.

```
\begin{equation}
\centering
\frac{\partial \overline{\rho}}{\partial{t}}+\frac{\partial (\overline{\rho}\overset{\sim}{u_i})} 
{\partial{t}}
 \end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: It will probably not end up at the exact same height, but note that the usual way to put a tilde over a variable is `\tilde{<variable>}`, not `\overset{\sim}{<variable>}`, i.e. `\tilde{u}_i`. (I would also lose the `\centering`. Usually equations are centred already. And if not, there is probably an option to toggle that on or off.)

Comment: When a variable is subscripted, the accent is usually set over the variable only; don't write `\dot{x_i}`, for instance, but `\dot{x}_i`. This case is similar, but `\sim` is not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By all means replace `\overset{\sim}{u}` with `\tilde{u}`. Optionally, replace `\overline{\rho}` with `\bar{\rho}`.

Here's a screenshot of `u` with various math-mode adornments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\bar{u} \tilde{u} \hat{u} \dot{u} \ddot{u} \acute{u} \grave{u} \check{u} \breve{u}$ 
$\bar{\bar{u}} \tilde{\tilde{u}} \hat{\hat{u}} \hat{\tilde{u}} \tilde{\bar{u}}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I have used `accents` package to put correctly (using the negative space `\kern-.2em`) the `\sim` symbol over the `u_i`. See the command `\accentset{\kern-.2em\sim}{u_i}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \bar{\rho}}{\partial{t}}+\frac{\partial (\bar{\rho}\accentset{\kern-.2em\sim}{u_i})} 
{\partial{t}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can use the "natural" code without the negative space:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \bar{\rho}}{\partial{t}}+\frac{\partial (\bar{\rho}\accentset{\sim}{u_i})} 
{\partial{t}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**This addition is due to the comment of the very good user @egreg that you can see below:** Following his advice putting

```
\accentset{\sim}{u}_i
```

you will have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \bar{\rho}}{\partial{t}}+\frac{\partial (\bar{\rho}\accentset{\sim}{u}_i)} 
{\partial{t}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just from comment by the user @barbara beeton into chat I use also the \widetilde command: here there is the output.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \bar{\rho}}{\partial{t}}+\frac{\partial (\bar{\rho}{\widetilde u}_i)} 
{\partial{t}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @down-voter: Is there a reason for a downvote for my answer? Where is my mistake?

Comment: +1. Happy to undo the downvoter's mistake. :-)

Comment: Sorry, that was me - I did change my mind immediately afterwards, and tried to cancel the vote, but it told me my vote was locked. I have been able to undo it now since you edited the post. My trigger-reaction reasoning/concern was that an inferior (imho) solution posted  hours after Mico's and moewe's might suggest to the asker that your answer was an improvement. Of course, your method does achieve the desired output. Apologies.

Comment: I'd recommend `\accentset{\sim}{u}_i` if `\tilde` is deemed too small.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much for your precious suggestion.

Comment: @Fintan Do not worry. I have only bad memories.